# Make request in NodeJs server?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a server http listener :

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
        res.writeHead(200,
        {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.write('aaa');
        res.end();
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('waiting......');
```

it is working find and do response.

[image]

Now  , I want - foreach client request - The server to perform *another* request and *append* a string `"XXX"`  :

So I wrote :

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
        host: 'www.random.org',
        path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};
http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
        res.writeHead(200,
        {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.write('aaa');

        http.request(options, function (r)
        {
                r.on('data', function (chunk)
                {
                        res.write('XXX');
                });
                r.on('end', function ()
                {
                        console.log(str);
                });
                res.end();
        });

        res.end();
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('waiting......');
```

So now foreach request , it should write : `aaaXXX` ( aaa+XXX)

But it doesnt work . it still egenrated the same output.

What am I dong wrong  ?

Comment: Look up socket.io or something WebSocket'ish for node. Out-of-the-box Node is still just a basic HTTP server. Real-time part comes out of WebSockets.

Comment: @psycketom But this basic Http server _can_ make another request of his own. thats what my question is about. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var http = require('http');
var options = {
        host: 'www.random.org',
        path: '/integers/?num=1&min=1&max=10&col=1&base=10&format=plain&rnd=new'
};
http.createServer(function (req, res)
{
        res.writeHead(200,
        {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
        });
        res.write('aaa');

        var httpreq = http.request(options, function (r)
        {
            r.setEncoding('utf8');
            r.on('data', function (chunk)
            {
                res.write(' - '+chunk+' - ');
            });
            r.on('end', function (str)
            {
                res.end();
            });

        });

        httpreq.end();

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('waiting......');
```

Also, worth reading [this article on nodejitsu](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request)

Comment: did I ever told you - I love you ? :-) Thanks a lot. it is working

Comment: first, i removed the `res.end()` because the previous `http.request` is asynchronous, and we should wait for it to finish, and another part is that we need to `.end()` the `http.request` to make it actually execute (we can POST some data before `.end()` so that is why we have that method)

Comment: why did you call `res.end();` on `r.on('data', function (chunk)` ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, good point, my fault.. this should be only in `.on('end'`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `res.end()` too early... you only want to do thing when EVERYTHING has been written (e.g. when r.on('end') is called).

For something like this, I would **highly** recommend using the excellent request library (https://github.com/mikeal/request).

This has a wonderful API, for example:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Comment: still , after removing the `end` ( the first one)  doesnt work....why cant he make another request and concat string ? ( I didnt change to your  solution yet. Im trying to figure out why myne aint working)